# Mysql query not working properly : SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'column' = 'some_string'

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have problem making this to work. I wannt to select row from database and render it to list. This is my code:

```
<ul class = "list">
  <li>
  <?php
    $x = 'some_string';
    $title = 'title';

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database') or die('Error connecting');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ==$x ORDER BY procenat DESC LIMIT 5";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  ?>
   <div id = "listdiv">
  <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
  ?>
    <h4><?php echo $row[$title]; ?> </h4>
  <?php 
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
  ?>
   </div> </li> </ul>
```

I tried with LIKE '%$x%' and that didn't work as well. And i tried ...  column = $x

Comment: why double equal? this is wrong, please remove `==` and try again with `=`

Comment: Are you getting any errors or nothing is displayed ?

Comment: You can also just do `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = "+$x+"ORDER BY..."`

Comment: `+` to concatenate in PHP code? It's not javascript

Comment: Frist, define /explain "didn't work". Second, have you tried to run the SQL directly in your console? does it work?

Comment: i tried with one = and that didnt work you can see that i wrote it to the end. #sharky

Comment: define "didn't work" means that nothing renders

Comment: are you sure your table name is `table` ?

Comment: check whether your query executes correctly or not, by prinitng `mysqli_error($dbc)`

Comment: I'm using 'table' in this question but my table name is different. But it match with table name in database if u think that is the problem.

Comment: @user3477366 try this `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ='".$x."' ORDER BY procenat DESC LIMIT 5"` use equals to for exact match and like for matching substring

Comment: try `LIKE $x` and wrap your string in `%%` inside variable `$x`

Comment: @shadow   It doesnt work in both cases. I triple triple check all strings for mistake and there isn't one.  I relly dont know what can it be.

Comment: did you checked whether your query executes or not ?

Comment: @user3477366 Then it seems that your column does not contain that value which is contained in $x

Comment: krishna can u tell me exact code to check it?

Comment: Can you try to echo $query; copy the query and execute in phpmyadmin?

Comment: try this `data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));`

Comment: @MarcoAcierno its not echo -ing antything

Comment: @krishna Nothing happened..

Comment: i put whole code in here  http://jsfiddle.net/Av9ue/

Comment: You can see here that there is no problem in the solutions provided in the answer section http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d62e/3

It definitely looks like either there is a syntax error which is not being shown probably because `error_reporting` might be turned off or there are no rows returned at all

Comment: when i try it on "writecodeonline" it says  Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()   ..  What that means?

Comment: That's because it doesn't support the `mysqli_*` API

Comment: but why is it not showing me any error? this is so frustrating

Comment: create a fiddle then we might be able to help you...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single equal sign along with quotes.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$x' ORDER BY procenat DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: again not working. I dont think the problem is with query since i tried almost anything.

Comment: Then load up phpmyadmin and make sure your query executes. Once we are done with that we will know for sure that the problem is on php's side.

Answer (score 0):

You should use LIKE operator like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name LIKE '%$x%' ORDER BY procenat DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: The % should be inside the query... %".$x."%

Comment: try with single quotes LIKE '%$x%'

Answer (score 0):

Change the query line as shown below

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '".$x."' ORDER BY procenat DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistake in your query just try this one.

1. replace `$x` with `'$x'`
2. replace `==` with `=`
3. run your query

```
$x = 'some_string';

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ='$x' ORDER BY procenat DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: it's not that. I think problem isn't in query.

Comment: i see that code and run that query so i found a prob in query.